# Rails 5 session.delete, not deleting cookies in my browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

I've been doing the exercise in

> https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login#sec-exercises_logging_out

It's says that I should confirm that the session is deleted after logging out, 
Does deleting the session using

```
session.delete(:user_id)
```

will make the cookie in my browser (Firefox), disappear?

Also, I've noticed that the content of the cookie changes when I'm visiting different pages in my website, is that an intended behavior? I also get cookies when visiting my website, for the first time, even when not logging on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will simply remove the key from the cookie as we can see in the source code https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb#L146.
It will in effect kill the authenticated but the cookie will still be there (it just won't say the user is authenticated anymore).

> Also, I've noticed that the content of the cookie changes when I'm visiting different pages in my website, is that an intended behavior?

Yes, if you're using CookieStore (which is the default way in Rails) all the data is stored on the cookie. So if you add or change fields, the cookie changes . (You will notice that the data is encrypted so this is secure). http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html

> I also get cookies when visiting my website, for the first time, even
>   when not logging on

It makes sense that Rails starts the session even before any authentication is happening - it's basically just an identifier without any data any it yet. A "Session" doesn't have to mean an authenticated user, you might want to save the user's preferred language or the time he opened the website even before he's authenticated.

Comment: Thank you, I was under the impression that its supposed to delete the cookie entirely. Although now that's clear, How am I supposed to confirm the session is removed through browser cookie.